# What's the difference between .img and .bin files for router firmwares?

Tags: router, firmware, openwrt, dd-wrt

OpenWRT and DD-WRT for example supply two files:

- factory     (.img)
- sysupgrade  (.bin)

Why is one a .img and the other a .bin?

Does it matter which one I just and if yes, when should I choose which?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OpenWRT and DD-WRT are just two different projects that "power" routers. Look at it as if you're comparing Linux distributions. Your question would be similar to asking what the difference between Ubuntu and Fedora is. They offer different features for different purposes.

About the files: One is an .img file, which completely erases the firmware and replaces it with a new image. The .bin is just a "sysupgrade" so it's just an upgrade that doesn't replace the current image.

Comment: nice answer! +1

Comment: So when do I have to use which? I tried upgrading through the web interface using a *.img* and it didn't work. Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: @Georg that depends on your needs, check out their respective websites for all features. As for updating, this will only work if you already have the custom firmware installed.

Comment: @BloodPhilia: Guessing with ".bin is just and "sysupgrade"" you meant to say ".bin is just a "sysupgrade"". Good analogy though. +1

Comment: @GeorgSchölly according to [GL.inet's documentation](https://docs.gl-inet.com/en/3/troubleshooting/debrick/) it's necessary to use `.img` files when you have a router that doesn't even boot due to a failed firmware installation. Some routers have _Uboot_ which allows you to replace the firmware on your router and it requires to upload a `.img` file.